# uninitialized constant SessionsController::User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, session, routes, controller

I'm trying to write a login system for my Rails App but I'm getting the sessions error. For more context, I don't have a user class but an EmployeeAuthentication and Employee class which has my login methods.

Currently, here is my sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
   def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
    if user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to home_path, notice: "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Username and/or password is invalid"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to home_path, notice: "Logged out!"
  end
end
```

And here is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # Semi-static page routes
  get 'home', to: 'home#index', as: :home
  get 'home/about', to: 'home#about', as: :about
  get 'home/contact', to: 'home#contact', as: :contact
  get 'home/privacy', to: 'home#privacy', as: :privacy
  get 'home/search', to: 'home#search', as: :search

  # Resource routes (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  resources :employees
  resources :stores
  resources :assignments
  resources :users
  resources :sessions

  # Custom routes
  patch 'assignments/:id/terminate', to: 'assignments#terminate', as: :terminate_assignment

  # You can have the root of your site routed with 'root'
  root 'home#index'


  get 'user/edit' => 'users#edit', :as => :edit_current_user
  get 'signup' => 'users#new', :as => :signup
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new', :as => :login
  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout


end
```

Comment: If you don't have a `User` class, then why do you do: `User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])`?

Comment: What is it exactly that your asking here? It's pretty obvious that of you don't have a User class referencing it will lead to a missing constant error. Is this some code you copied from somewhere but you don't understand how to adapt to your application or are you just looking to get someone else to do your job for you?

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing authentication from scratch for educational purposes? If not, it is better not to "reinvent the wheel". Authentication and its close sibling Authorization deal specifically with the security of your application and you should not leave that security in your own hands (especially if you have never written a complete authentication system from scratch in the past and tested the crap out of it).

When building Rails applications, I tend to use the '[devise](https://rubygems.org/gems/devise)' gem for authentication and '[cancancan](https://rubygems.org/gems/cancancan)' gem for authorization. These two gems have been around almost as long as Rails has and have been tried and tested over the years, they are proven secure options for implementing authentication and authorization in your web applications.